# How do I avoid an empty line in floating text in Jasper Reports if text fits exactly to text field?

Tags: jasper-reports

Using Jasper Reports Library 5.6.0 I designed a report with floating text fields with line wrapping. One example for such a text field is the following:

```
    <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="false">
        <reportElement key="textField-25" positionType="Float" 
                 stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" mode="Opaque" x="172" y="0" 
                 width="122" height="12" uuid="f5617e21-e2db-4ea7-9311-82c83805827f">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="px"/>
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
        </reportElement>
        <box>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
        <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
        <font size="8" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
    </textElement>
```

This works quiet well for short text, when no line wrapping is necessary, and for long texts, when line wrapping puts some text on the next line or lines.

If the text fits exactly to the length of the text field, and if I use the report library on linux systems, the line is wrapped even though it's not necessary. In this case it looks like the text is aligned to the top rather than aligned to center as it should be.

Of course I checked that the text really is not followed by blanks and it is not.

I wasn't able to reproduce the problem on Windows, only when the software is deployed to a linux server. Unfortunately in the production environment we have linux, and unfortunately there will be some users who'll have to face the problem quiet often.

Is there any solution to avoid the line break in cases like this?

Comment: Do you output to PDF?

Comment: Yes, the output is to PDF.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. A frame causes the problem.
It was the case for me. I removed the frame and all is correct.

In fact, the frame have a minimum height. So, when an element wrap, the frame readapt its height to have its min height.

Hope this will help some one!